# Value of LED current limiting resistor incorrect?

Tags: led, current, resistors

I am confused as to why the value of R297 is 1.8k in the circuit below:

[image]

Shouldn't the value of the current limiting resistor be = (5-2.35)/.025 = 106

Thanks

Comment: 25mA is the maximum current the LED should be driven at. There's no harm in using a lower current.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They’re choosing to drive the LED at about 1.5mA, which may be bright enough for their application, especially if the LED is high efficiency.

Rarely is it useful (or wise) to drive an indicator LED at its max rated current. Beyond a certain point the LED doesn’t appear much brighter, given the eye’s logarithmic response to light, so you’re shedding all that power in the LED for nothing.

Comment: And, I might add, needlessly stressing the LED.

Comment: The human eye is more sensitive to green than other colors, and if this is a high-efficiency LED, the low current can be very much warranted just from a comfort perspective.

Comment: great answer thanks. Ill try not to blind anyone